# Forcing UINavigationController in portrait mode only

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, rotation, autorotate

I have a MovieViewController as a child of UINavigationController. I used MPMoviePlayerViewController to play video streaming triggered from MovieViewController , and in that video view, it can change the orientation to landscape or portrait. All I need is, when I tap the done button the MovieViewController turn to portrait mode again because it's only support portrait mode.

Here is the code

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return(UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait);
}

- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate {
    return FALSE;
}
```

But when I tap the done button it's crashing, 
"preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation must return a supported interface orientation!"

note: I called the moviePlayer modally.

```
NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"URL"];
player =[[MyMoviePlayerViewController alloc]
                                      initWithContentURL:movieURL];
[self presentViewController:player animated:YES completion:nil];
```

So after It is called, there is done button which will dismiss the view. The problem is when I view the movie in landscape mode and tap done button, it crashed because I only have 1 supported interface (portrait).

Comment: consider this solution which creates a category on navigation controller which sets it up for allowed/dissalowed orientations http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26205269/force-view-controller-to-portrait-only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the answers but this is the code that solve all my problem above.

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a few things you need to do.

First, remove this line - it's deprecated.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
   return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Second, subclass your UINavigationController and add the following code:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations 
{
    NSUInteger orientation = UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    if ([self.navigationController.visibleViewController isMemberOfClass:[MPMoviePlayerViewController class]]) {
        orientation = UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    }
    return orientation;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate 
{
    return YES;
}
```

In this code, I assume you're pushing your MPMovieController (via your navigationController) on top of MovieViewController.