# Force view controller to portrait only

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, rotation

In my application I am trying to force a view controller to be portrait only. I am using the code below but nothing is really happening. I am still able to see the screen in landscape as in portrait?

I have enabled landscape (left/right), portrait in my project settings.

What am I do wrong?

ViewController.m

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Comment: Is your view controller embedded in a another controller, such as navigation controller or tab bar controller?

Comment: Yes it's in a navigation controller :)

Answer (score 2):

If you VC is embedded in a navigation or tab bar controller you need to create a category on that controller. This is an example that allow navigation controller rotate in all ways:

```
#import "UINavigationController+RotationAll.h"

@implementation UINavigationController (RotationAll)

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}

@end
```

Comment: I want one controller to have all rotate possibilities (video) and other to have just portrait. Can you explain your code a bit more? Why the import like that? why (RotationAll) by the implementation

Comment: The import that way is because it is a category on UINavigationController. RotationAll is just the category name. The important is that this override the UINavigationController interface orientation. You can use it on one controller and change it supporting only portraits modes for the other one.

Comment: which category names are available for example? :)

Comment: Whatever you want. Have a look at [this category tutotial](http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/categories.html).